# Cross fading several audio files using sox

Tags: bash, sound, scripts, sh, sox

I'm trying to cross-fade several audio files together with a 3 second cross-fade and join them together in to one file with sox.

I can join several files together by the command below but not sure how to cross fade between each one:

```
sox $(ls /tmp/a*.wav | sort -n) /tmp/out/out.wav
```

I can cross fade two files with the commands below but not sure how to combine the first line that joins several files together with the second line that splices / cross fades

```
sox 100hz.wav 440hz.wav out.wav splice $(soxi -D 100hz.wav),3
```

I found this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955320/crossfading-a-group-of-audio-files-with-sox-splice) but the answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: the command you ran does not look anything like the command in the link you referenced. If sox does not work try Ardour . It is a bit heavy for what you are doing, but it has a lot of features and this sort of splice would be trivial.

Comment: ffmpeg is the best command line tool, IMHO.

Comment: Correct because the link I reference the person also said the code they used didn't work for them. I need to do this via command line. It's several files could be 50 and Ardour and Audacity are nice but I need to automate the process.

Comment: I've used ffmpeg before do you have an example of how to do what I'm trying to do?  PS you do realize I'm only using audio.  No video is used.

Comment: http://nerdcore-enthusiasm.blogspot.com/2010/05/crossfade-two-videos-clips-from-command_340.html and http://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg no reason ffmpeg can not manage audio only

Comment: Thanks but I'm noticing a pattern of only showing examples of one or two files, never anymore files than this as you can see from my question I can already cross fade with sox in one line using the splice command.  I even included a working example.

Comment: Aye, I do not think the command line tools are going to be as easy as the graphical tools on this one. This is the sort of operation Ardour is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a script [crossfade_cat.sh](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Scripts) as I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652490/cross-fading-several-audio-files-using-sox/28670099#28670099) by [Frank Zalcow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812618/frank-zalkow) on Stack Overflow.

I am using this script (given in the answer) to call it

```
crossfade_dur=1
i=0

for file in *.wav
do

    i=$((i+1))

    if [ $i -eq 1 ]
    then
        cp $file mix.wav
    else
        crossfade_cat.sh $crossfade_dur mix.wav $file auto auto
    fi

done
```

I had all the files in the same directory and made the scripts executable. It worked for me